# Shall CBSA suspect non-prescription vitamins and supplements mailed to Canada, from Western Europe?

Tags: canada, medical

My family in Canada rely long term on, **but cannot afford**, NON-prescription vitamins and supplements in Canada. They can be bought MORE CHEAPLY ***without prescription*** in Western Europe, where I am working. The pills come in bottles like that below.

Even if legal, shall mailing supplements to Canada from Western Europe arouse suspicion from Canada Border Services Agency (CBSA)? My family and I do not mind CBSA scanning or X-raying the bottles, but we don't want to be blacklisted or watchlisted by the CBSA!

[image]

Comment: ttps://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/drugs-health-products/compliance-enforcement/importation-exportation/personal-use-health-products-guidance/document.html#a6.2

_Residents of Canada and visitors are permitted to bring into Canada a personal use quantity (a 90-day supply or single course of treatment) of an OTC medication, NHP, VHP or a medical device for personal use without requiring specific licences for the import._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check yourself using the [CFIA Automated Import Reference System (AIRS)](https://inspection.canada.ca/importing-food-plants-or-animals/plant-and-plant-product-imports/airs/eng/1300127512994/1300127627409#). The  CBSA officers at the airport showed me this, when I was inquiring about bringing back exotic foods prior to a trip a couple years ago.

## See also [Memorandum D19-9-1](https://cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/dm-md/d19/d19-9-1-eng.html) issued Ottawa, January 24, 2017. ISSN 2369-2391.

> #### Personal Importation of Natural Health Products and Non-Prescription Drugs
>
> 31. Residents, non-residents and visitors to Canada can import for their own use or for a person under that individual's care a single course of treatment or a 90-day supply of natural health products and non-prescription drugs. The drug must be packaged in the hospital, pharmacy dispensing  or retail packaging, or have the original label affixed to it clearly indicating what the product is and what it contains.
> 32. The CBSA may detain and refer natural health products and non-prescription drugs to Health Canada when these requirements are not met.

Comment: Are we certain that vitamin supplements are "natural health products" or "non-prescription drugs"?  I think there's a fairly good chance that they aren't.